# Unable to cast to a Custom Receiver App from JW Player 8

Tags: jwplayer, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I'm trying to cast videos from a web application using JW Player 8 to a Custom Cast Receiver App. I've registered the receiver app, whitelisted the device that I'm casting to (the app isn't yet published), and I'm passing in the following when initializing the JW Player:

```
let player = jwplayer('video-player');

player.setup({
    file: 'video.mp4',
    cast: {
        appid: MY_CUSTOM_APP_ID
    }
});
```

Every time I go to cast, it casts to "Default Media Receiver". I can't seem to get it to cast to my custom app.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? It appears to be JW Player-related, as the player has a built-in sender app that doesn't look to be requesting the custom receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I have JW Player to thank for this one (said sarcastically)... Looks like their documentation is wrong. Their docs read `cast.appid`,  but it is in fact `cast.customAppId`. Swapped to the later, and it's now loading up my custom app.

... Now to figure out why the video isn't loading... :P

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem,

if you use cast.appid the video is play normally on default receiver app,

but if you use case.customAppId video will not play on your custom receiver app. i think i'll build CAF receiver manually.